# ADA locked on Trust - 2 delegations*( only one should be active ) - Now cant claim & reflects 2 balances

Tags: plutus, staking, cardano-foundation

Good afternoon all

I recently unstaked or attempted to unstake ada & it looked as if it was going from 1 validator to another , my problem is everything is stuck now. I cannot claim , I cannot unstake ; I have almost 19500ada & 1 page shows me 16 rewards another shows 3 currently , I unstaked last December 4th received 7.45 & now when try says insuficient balance so I sent 33 ada to use & now all ada is stuck & refreshing shows 2 different amounts & this error message comes up.  stating invalid amounts & path I have tried claiming & unstaking from my both please advise I need my ada moved.

Comment: If you feel comfortable doing so, it would be easiest if you could post your address or stake key. This way members of this community could have a look at the blockchain and analyze what's going on. From your description it's hard to tell what exactly you have done and what could have gone wrong.